# Transformation XSLT

Tags: json, xslt, wso2, transformation, payload

I have a payload response Json as below

```
{
    "instance" :{
        "instanceId" : "AC"
    },
    "caseDetails":{
        "id" : "100",
        "decisionMaker" : "gljslgkj",
        "state" : "decisionDiffused",
 
        "caseTexts":[
            {
                "type":"DELIBERATION",
                "language":"FR"
            },
            {
                "type":"DELIBERATION",
                "language":"NL"
            }
        ],
 
        "workflow":{
            "locationFR": "dlfsjflj",
            "locationNL": "jfdlksjfk",
            "locationValidators" : [
                {
                    "lastName":"lastName",
                    "firstName": "firstName"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

this is the response that I got from backend, when I transformed it to XML (using property messageType)
the caseTexts part is getting as this

```
              <bos:caseTexts>
                <bos:type>DELIBERATION</bos:type>
                <bos:language>FR</bos:language>
              </bos:caseTexts>
              <bos:caseTexts>
                <bos:type>DELIBERATION</bos:type>
                <bos:language>NL</bos:language>
              </bos:caseTexts>
```

I want it as follow : **caseTexts** and list of **caseText** as child

```
  <bos:caseTexts>
    <bos:caseText>
        <bos:type>DELIBERATION</bos:type>
        <bos:language>FR</bos:language>
    </bos:caseText>
    ....
</bos:caseTexts>
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this would be to create a caseTexts xml element, do a "for-each" [1] inside it for each caseTexts while doing a "copy-of" [2] of the content inside the caseTexts object.

[1]https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_for_each.asp

[2]https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_copy-of.asp